Statistics evaluating two variables in several groups
I am not sure what kind of statistics (MVA) would be used in the following experimental scenario:
Under different conditions I measure two (log norm distributed) parameters and want to assess the separate and/or combined effect of the conditions on the parameters.
In practice the data could look like this:
The cell-number of each bacterium is counted in a co-culture of two bacteria measured under different conditions in several replicates (log2 cell number in data matrix):



:Experiment
:BacA:
:BacB:




CondA_rep1
1.5
1.1


CondA_rep2
1.3
1.2


CondA_rep3
1.5
1.1


CondB_rep1
3.0
4.1


CondB_rep2
2.9
4.2


CondB_rep3
3.2
3.9


CondC_rep1
6.0
2.1


CondC_rep2
5.7
1.8


CondC_rep3
5.3
2.1



For statistical testing I could transform the data into the ratio of BacX/BacY and the total number of cells in each experiment. Or leave the values as is.
With ANOVA I could test the ratio and/or the total Number of cells, however, I want to test the data together (Ratio of BacX/BacY AND total growth; or Cell number of BacX AND BacY).
So far my research suggest I may use something like MANOVA?
I hope the question is understandable. So far I have only used test on single factors/variables where a T-test or ANOVA was all I needed and even finding the right terminology to find appropriate statistics by online searches was not very successful.
So any help would be appreciated.

I am a bit confused; you say that the data in the table is $log_2$ of the counts. But then (the way I read it), you want to take the ratio of these numbers; if they are log transformed, you should take the difference of these (log of ratio = diff of logs). Note that for ANOVA or MANOVA, you do not need the marginal distributions to be normally distributed, only the residuals, so taking the log of your lognormal variables may not be necessary (but still meaningful for your application)?

Yes what you say is right, if I use the ratio and not the values I would either use the log-difference or use the ratio of the original values and log-transform these ratios. For statistical testing we usually use log2 values in my application. Do you think MANOVA is the right test for the above example?

Instead of worrying about terminology for different types of tests, focus on the question you want to answer. In your situation, a multiple regression model would seem to be a good choice, as you only have one type of outcome: the number of counts of bacteria.
The trick: along with the experimental conditions, think of your two types of bacteria as predictors of what that number will be. Allow for different effects of the conditions for the two types of bacteria by including an interaction between condition and bacterial type.
If you want to estimate the total number of bacteria in each condition, after you fit the regresssion model you can use post-modeling tools like those in the R emmeans package to evaluate any combination of predictor values that you want. That will take into account both the point estimates and the associated errors around the fit.
The above model with interactions is conceptually similar to a 2-way ANOVA, but ANOVA probably isn't a good choice for your count-based outcomes. The statistical test should take into account how the errors around a model's predictions change with the predicted value. ANOVA classically assumes that errors are the same around all model predictions. With count data the errors typically increase with the number of predicted counts.
It looks like you have used a $\log_2$ transformation to address that type of issue. That might work in practice, in a multiple regression or ANOVA model, if the transformation makes the errors relatively independent of the model predictions. This answer outlines several types of transformations that might be considered; a square-root transformation has often been used for count data.
When you work with $\log_2$-transformed data and then do regression/ANOVA, however, you are modeling the means of the $\log_2$-transformed counts, not the means of the counts themselves. A generalized linear regression model appropriate to counts might be a better choice. This answer outlines the Poisson, quasi-Poisson, and negative binomial models appropriate for count data. Such models can be fit with the standard glm() function in R software. When you do that you should go back to the original number of observed counts; the $\log_2$ values in your table look like they have already been normalized in some way, maybe per milliliter of broth. Do the analysis in the original count scale first, then adjust the final results to a per-volume basis if you wish.
I recommend that you study the Technical Perspective by the Pollards, Empowering statistical methods for cellular and molecular biologists, Molecular Biology of the Cell 30: 1359-1368, 2019, for how to analyze the types of data typically generated in molecular and cellular biology. Note in particular Figure 2, which shows how the choice of statistical analysis should be based on the nature of the outcome variable.
